# Test automation tool compatible with Python scripts

Tags: python, linux, automation, apk, katalon-studio

Can you recommend the tool for automation of my APK scripts in Python, which is compatible with Linux and has a free trial, so I can try it out first?

The main reason I need this tool - is to make test automation implemented in the company I work for, so we can see if tests pass or fail. 
As for now everything only works on my local DB, but we need something better and more powerful than that.

So far I found some tools, for example, Katalon Studio tool, which is ok, but I need to revert my code into Java in order to use it and it doesn't worth it.

Comment: Please read this thread on what questions are on-topic for stack overflow, specifically item #4; https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: ok, thanks, will do

Comment: Buildbot? ......